# Drop email send into different folder

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have a mail box where all support emails come through to the default location "Inbox", we recently added in some new programs with automatically run every day. We've set them so when they run, it will send an email to this mail box.

What I want to do is separate out the user requests from the automation emails

I have this block of code which will send out an email and I've been trying to route it to the Automation folder

```
var email = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, emailBody)
{
    IsBodyHtml = true
};

var client = new SmtpClient("", 0)
{
    DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory,
    PickupDirectoryLocation = @"\\Automation\",
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
};

client.Send(email);
```

[image: Text]

I keep getting the error that the network path does not exist?

Comment: SMTP just sends the mail to the address. It has no knowledge of the internal structure of the mailbox, it cannot see folders etc, it only knows about the address. `PickupDirectoryLocation` does not control where the email is delivered to, it controls the folder where messages are placed for delivery to a local SMTP server for **sending**. Nothing to do with delivery. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_PickupDirectoryLocation explains more.

Comment: Email sending code can not control in which folder the email should be delivered to. It's the rule set at the email client.

Comment: If you want to control where the email ends up when it's delivered, this is internal to your mailbox account. If you use Outlook for example, you can set up a rule which can move emails to a specified folder depending on factors such as the name/email of the sender, or the content of the subject line, etc.  If you have office365 you could use Power Automate to do something like that, too. Maybe even you could rethink the whole concept and get it to just create tickets in your helpdesk system directly instead of messing about with emails. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PickupDirectoryLocation` is for local pickup. Its intention is not to set destination folder. And you cannot do it with SMTP in anyway.

> **SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation Property** 
> Gets or sets the folder where applications save mail messages to be
> processed by the local SMTP server.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation?view=netcore-3.1)